# JQuery in second document ready not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have two document ready events.

**First**, on page (working post request inserting html form),  inserted by my WP shortcode:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery.post(
            ajaxUrl,
            {
                action: 'action',
                nonce: 'nonce'
            },
            function(response) {
                $('#place').removeClass('preloader');
                $('#place').html(response);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

**Second (it worked until I added first code to page**), in js file loaded in footer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
/* some ajax call with form data*/
    });
});
```

Second ready event fired, but `$('#myform').submit` not working.
Can you help me?

Comment: if you debug the second one, i think you will see `$('#myform')` doesn't return any element.

Comment: It may be. Form with id `myform` is inserted by post in first event. So, when second js is loaded `myform` is not in document... How to solve this?

Comment: Would make sense to put `$('#myform').submit()` after `$('#place').html(response);`, since the dependency is there.

Comment: of course, it's obvious solution, but it will broke general methods.

Comment: There are several solutions to that, 1) you can put `$('#myform').submit()` inside the form html so it will be self-executed when $('#place').html(response); is called. 2) make the method smarter by parsing the response and to check has a form element w/ submit button 3) use event based communication between the 2 piece of code.

Comment: many thanks to you. I will try 1 and 2. But If i reload src with second script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to use document.ready function. If you include scripts at the footer level after all your required dom elements, they will run after the rest of the document and elements have loaded- thus, getting rid of the need for on document ready functions.

It's unclear what you are doing with the functions and how they could interact, but if one is changing the other make sure you're getting the elements you need. A good way to test is pop open the developer console in the browser and copy/paste your javascript code to see what works and what doesn't. You can type javascript in the console and run it real time on the dom loaded in your browser.

Comment: Yes so it's important to include your script at the bottom of the page after the dom is loaded. Also, if the second function depends on the first, call it after the first is completed. No document ready is needed